# Yii2 basic template manual deployment in subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii2, web-deployment

I need to deploy a web package manually in a subdirectory in the server. I basically have to separate the english site from the spanish one in different subdirectories.

Structure:

- /www/english-site
- /www/spanish-site

How I managed to deploy a Yii2 web is by taking /web contents and moving them up 1 folder, leaving everything in server root level.

When I do this, but instead I take all contents to a subdirectory so I can have 2 separated webs in the same hosting, I get the following errors.

1. I try to enter /site/action and it simply throws:

> File not found.

2. The only page that actually loads is the /site/index which has trouble loading libraries and images:

> GET domain.com/css/libs/swiper.min.css
>
> GET domain.com/img/bg.png 404 (Not Found)
>
> GET domain.com/img/logo.png 404 (Not Found)
>
> GET domain.com/js/libs/swiper.min.js

## .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

## index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);

require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
$config = require(__DIR__ . '/config/web.php');

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

## Current folder structure (/www/spanish-site)

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je4wO.png)

I'm sorry if this is easy and obvious, but I haven't found a solution searching for hours.

Thank you!

---

## UPDATE

I think I've sorted this out.

I changed the .htaccess to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . SUBDIRECTORY/index.php
```

Comment: Be sure that DocumentRoot in apache config is set to /www/spanish-site/web for spanish domain and to /www/english-site/web for english domain.
Do you access index.php as domain.com/web/site/index? or domain.com/site/index?

Comment: And why don't you use internationalization features? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-i18n.html

Comment: Also check apache access.log and error.log. Enable yii2 logging and check logs in runtime/logs